# I need to use Slick Carousel as a Hero Slider in my Website- JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm still learning javascript and now I'm trying to get Slick Carousel working. I need it as a hero slider in my webpage

Slick carousel on github:
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Hero Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="single-item">
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604467758117-72d987cb513b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="test"></div>
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604475935971-c390654d2332?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=321&q=80" alt="test"></div>
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604470690311-c4136298584d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=714&q=80" alt="test"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.single-item').slick();
    });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Can you guide me what is missing to make this running? As said I need it to be a hero slider and also I will add a header to this webpage after this. So this should work with that too.

Comment: Always check the console for errors in JS. If you fix your typo here, ie. remove the extra `});`, then your code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was just a small typo.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Hero Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="single-item">
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604467758117-72d987cb513b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="test"></div>
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604475935971-c390654d2332?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=321&q=80" alt="test"></div>
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604470690311-c4136298584d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=714&q=80" alt="test"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.single-item').slick();
    //Removed a }); here
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```